# Slider doesn't work properly

Tags: commerce

I am testing with the SShop theme. The sliders I have added are not shown properly.

> [image: Weird slider]

All the pictures have the same format: 1600x800.

Home >> Administration >> Reports >> Recent log messages does not give any error messages.
In the [drupalrootfolder]/libraries folder the following is shown:

- bootstrap
- colorbox
- fontaweson
- jquery.cycle
- jquery.hoverIntent
- jquery.pause
- json2
- smartmenus
- stacktable.js

I also installed the SShop demo theme. A crosscheck did not reveal any big differences.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the images in the demo theme show up properly?  If so, when you add the images in the demo theme to your site, what happens?

Comment: If I add one of my pictures to the demo site, the picture is not shown correctly.
If I add one of the pictures from the demosite to my site the picture is not shown correctly.

It is weird, isn't it?

Comment: I have done some more testing. If there is only one picture in the slider, then the picture is shown correctly. As soon as there are more than one pictures in the slider then all the pictures are shown incorrectly.

Comment: All the pictures have the same size: 1600x800, 72 DPI and Resampling FANT.

Comment: In that case, I would try filing a support request in the module's issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/sshop?categories=All

Comment: Done. See https://www.drupal.org/project/sshop/issues/3189319#comment-13945455.